# How can I get a dependency of "default-jre" to work for .rpm packages?

Tags: rpm, java

After asking the question [Can I indicate that a .deb package depends on Java, but not specify what implementation (e.g. OpenJDK, IcedTea, Oracle)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291783/58188), I was helpfully informed that I could include a dependency of `default-jre` when building my package, which would automatically find an appropriate version of Java to install before installing the package.

However, when I try to do the same for a .rpm package, I instead get the following error:

> Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:
>
> 1. nothing provides default-jre needed by

How can I get `default-jre` to work with a .rpm package as it does with a .deb package?

To be clear, I want this to be an automatic dependency so that a user can take the .rpm package and install the app (and Java if not already installed) without needing to do anything on their own.

Answer (score 1):

```
Requires: java
```

Should do almost what you need. At least on RHEL/CentOS all Java packages habe a `Provides: java` and that will be pulled in with the above `Requires`. However you will get the latest Java if none is installed, not the default one. If one is already installed the dependency is already fulfilled and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

if you have downloaded the package to your local system then run the below

`yum localinstall default-jre.rpm`

[reference link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-centos-and-fedora)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make this a dependency on the package so that an end user doesn't have to run a command on their own. It should be a one-step install of the .rpm. I've modified my question to clarify this.